# Can I change the apk certificate in the device?

Tags: android

My device is rooted.

My app is system app.

I want to let user knows the app will change certificate.
The old apk use a certificate created by myself,but the new apk need system certificate.
I can resign the apk in my computer by **platform.x509.pem,platform.pk8,signapk.jar** these three files.

Now can I reinstall the new signed app?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the signing key of an application once it has been installed, any certificate change will be rejected by the package manager. The new app would need a different package name if you've already placed one on the system partition with the wrong key. Otherwise the old one would have to be completely removed from the device first so no traces of the old signature are left.